# Return CGPoint from extension

Tags: struct, swift, cgpoint

Im trying to return a `CGPoint` from a `CGPoint extension`.

I have this `extension`:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func Multiply(factor:Int) {
        return self.x*factor, self.y*factor
    }
}
```

Now, no matter how I change the `return line` I get a different error.
Ive tried to put `{},[],()` around it, Ive tried `{1,2},[1,2],(1,2)`

And `CGPointMake()` isnt allowed.

And like I could in Obj-C `{.x = 1, .y = 2}`

Nothing seems to work and I get a different error for each.

Comment: why dont you return a cgpointmake(self.x*factor,self.y*factor) ? CGPoint is allowed you need to import QuartzCore

Comment: It is not possible: CGPoint is not convertible to ()

Comment: what is the difference between CGPointMake() and CGPoint(x:,y:)

Comment: CGPoint is a Swift func while CGPointMake is C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to declare the return type (CGPoint):

```
extension CGPoint {
    func Multiply(factor:CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x*factor, y:self.y*factor)
    }
}
```

That should compile.

Comment: Hahaha im so stupid... Thanks totally forgot it Swift is a little weird :P

Comment: And factor had to be of type CGFloat, i can accept soon

Comment: True, because x and y are floats, factor has to be a float or you need to manually convert it to one within the function . I edited the answer...

Comment: @Arbitur I agree that swift is indeed a little weird